# Finding asymptotic curve

Tags: differential-geometry

For a given surface with parametrization $f(u,v)$, I obtained following diff.equation for asymptotic curve
$$v^2k_3^2\mbox{d}u^2+2k_3\mbox{d}u\mbox{d}v=0.$$ Solwing this I got one solution $\mbox{d}u=0,$ i.e. $u=const.,$ so $v-$curves are asymptotic, and another one equation is
$$v^2k_3^2\mbox{d}u+2\mbox{d}v=0.$$ Now I'm stuck. Is there some elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Is $k_3$ a constant? First of all, you should have the equation 
$$v^2k_3 du + 2 dv = 0,$$
which is a separable differential equation (assuming $k_3$ is constant). Write this as $k_3\,du = -2 v^{-2}\,dv$ and integrate.